# How to get data from an url?

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to use python to get the data from "https://jobs.51job.com/jinan-gxq/139057256.html?s=gsxq_zwlb_gsxqlb&t=17"

I expect to get data like below but I get a script.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
url = 'https://jobs.51job.com/jinan-gxq/139057256.html?s=gsxq_zwlb_gsxqlb&t=17'
res = requests.get(url)
print(res.text)
```

The output is:

```
'<html><script>\nvar arg1=\'6C00B31D29AE4156FC48C6823C7476185B28DB15\';\nvar _0x4818=[\'\\x63\\x73\\x4b\\x48\\x77\\x71\\x4d\\x49\',\'\\x5a\\x73\\x4b\\x4a\\x77\\x72\\x38\\x56\\x65\\x41\\x73\\x79\',\'\\x55\\x63\\x4b\\x69\\x4e\\x38\\x4f\\x2f\\x77\\x70\\x6c\\x77\\x4d\\x41\\x3d\\x3d\',\'\\x4a\\x52\\x38\\x43\\x54\\x67\\x3d\\x3d\',\'\\x59\\x73\\x4f\\x6e\\x62\\x53\\x45\\x51\\x77\\x37\\x6f\\x7a\\x77\\x71\\x5a\\x4b\\x65\\x73\\x4b\\x55\\x77\\x37\\x6b\\x77\\x58\\x38\\x4f\\x52\\x49\\x51\\x3d\\x3d\',\'\\x77\\x37\\x6f\\x56\
```

How can I get the data?

[image]

Comment: You're retrieving the HTML as text. As such, the data is probably there, except it's in the middle of a sea of tags. You've got a few options. The first one is: look at the network traffic and see if you can find an endpoint that retrieves that data in a more usable way, like JSON, and use that endpoint instead of the URL poiting to the HTML. Another option would be trying to use BeautifulSoup, or Selenium, or something of the sort, and navigate the page through the tags finding the data you need.

Comment: Selenium can be a solution. However, how to use BeautifulSoup decrypt the data? By the way, I cannot see any tags.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is just for finding HTML tags and data in them. But if Selenium could work and you know how to use it, then use selenium. And I do see tags. In your example output, at the beginning there is `<html><script>`, there have to be more tags later in the output.

Comment: Can I execute the script and get the data?

Comment: Uhm... Yes, you need to write a script... Is there something I'm not understanding?